# Finding the limit $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$

Tags: limits

I am trying to find the limit 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \sin^n \left( \frac{x}{2} \right) + \left( \frac{1}{\pi} \cdot \operatorname{arccot}(x) \right)^n \right)$$
Where $\operatorname{arccot}(x)$ is defined [like this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Relationships_among_the_inverse_trigonometric_functions):

[image: arccot(x)]

And the answer is obviously something like this
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1, \quad \text{when } x \in \{ \, (1+4k) \pi \mid k \in \mathbb{Z} \, \}; \\
\text{non-existent}, \quad \text{when } x \in \{ \, (-1+4k) \pi \mid k \in \mathbb{Z} \, \}; \\
0, \quad \text{otherwise}; 
\end{cases}$$

But what is the meaning of $\operatorname{arccot}(x)$ in this situation? My limit doesn't really assess it in any way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: the range of $\operatorname{arccot}$ is $(0, \pi)$, if I'm not mistken, so $|\operatorname{arccot}(x)/\pi| < 1$ for any real $x$.  That takes care of the second piece.  For the first piece, there are three cases, because $\sin(x/2)$ can be $-1$, $1$, or strictly between $-1$ and $1$.

The function $\operatorname{arccot}$ is a lot less commmonly used than $\tan^{-1}$.  I am pretty sure $\operatorname{arccot}(x)$ is the (unique) angle $\theta$ in $(0, \pi)$ with $\cot \theta = x$.

Answer (score 0):

The link you gave had the range of $arccot(x)$:
$$0 \lt arccot(x) \lt \pi$$
Then:
$$0 \lt \frac{1}{\pi}arccot(x) \lt 1$$
Now consider again your problem and you'll see that:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}{(\frac{1}{\pi}arccot(x))^n} = 0
$$

Comment: But apparently $\lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{x \to -\infty} \left( \frac{1}{\pi} \operatorname{arccot} (x) \right)^n = 1$ and that confuses me.

Comment: @Pranasas: when you define $f(x)$, you let $n \to \infty$ _while x stays the same_